# (Discord selfbot) Is there anyway to response if 'hi' in someone message

Tags: discord, bots

Is there anyway to make the selfbot response 'hello' if 'hi' is in someone message?
Like

A: hi? Anyone here?
The bot: hello

The bot response because 'hi' is in A's message.
I think it's not possible because i tried many Discord selfbot library and none of library  work (Python)

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because selfbots are against the [TOS](https://support.discord.com/hc/en-us/articles/115002192352-Automated-user-accounts-self-bots-)

Comment: I know selfbot are against the TOS but im creating it just for fun.

Answer (score 2):

Which library are you using?

I made a discord bot with [discord.js](https://discord.js.org/#/) (Javascript), and with that you can receive an event every time someone talks in your discord server and then respond depending on the contents of the message.

First you start your discord client (the Intents may vary depending on what you want to do):

```js
     const discordClient =  new Client({ intents: [Intents.FLAGS.DIRECT_MESSAGES, Intents.FLAGS.GUILD_MESSAGES] })
```

Then the idea is to get the content of every new message and answer properly, once you have created your discord client, you will need to set up an event listener like this one:

```js
    discordClient.on('messageCreate', message => {
        const content = messageReceived.content.toLocaleLowerCase()
        if (content === 'hi') {
            messageReceived.channel.send("hello, I'm a bot!")
        }
    })
```

And don't forget to login with your discord bot key

```js
    const discordKey = "YOUR DISCORD BOT KEY"
    discordClient.login(discordKey)
```

You can also see the repository for my bot [here](https://github.com/littlesalty/discordBot).

And for your use case you would want to mainly focus on some parts insid [discord.ts](https://github.com/littlesalty/discordBot/blob/main/src/discord.ts).

Hopefully this helps.

Comment: Im using Discum and Discord.py for Python tho. Is there anyway to do that with Python?

Answer (score 0):

Here are some basic examples using `discord.js` within `node.js`.

**Simple Response**

To send a response, simply check if the user's message contains the desired input you want your bot to respond to.

```js
if(message.content.toLowerCase().includes("ping") {
     message.reply("Pong!")
}
```

**Multiple Responses**

This is a much more efficient method of responding to multiple inputs. This includes using an array.

```js
const array = [
     "hello",
     "hola",
     "bonjour"
]

if(array.some(word => message.content.toLowerCase().includes(`${word}`)) {
     message.reply("Hello!")
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's the code

---Starts From Here:---

```
// type `await lib.` to display API autocomplete
const lib = require('lib')({token: process.env.STDLIB_SECRET_TOKEN});

// Only respond to messages containing "hi", "hey", "hello", or "sup"
if (context.params.event.content.match(/hi|hey|hello|sup/i)) {
  let messageContent = context.params.event.content.match(/hi|hey|hello|sup/i);

  await lib.discord.channels['@0.3.0'].messages.create({
    channel_id: context.params.event.channel_id,
    content: `${messageContent[0]} to you too `,
    message_reference: {
      message_id: context.params.event.id
    }
  });
}
```

--Ends--

[Image of code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hUkBV.png)

---

I suggest using autocode.com it will really help you in coding life. I use it myself.

Here's a small guide https://autocode.com/guides/how-to-build-a-discord-bot/

Answer (score 0):

If your banned using discord selfbot, that's not my fault

```py
from discord.ext import commands

client = commands.Bot(
  command_prefix='-',
  self_bot=True,
  help_command=None
)

@client.event
async def on_message(message):
 if message.author == client.user:
      return

 if message.content == 'Hello!':
            await message.channel.send("Hi how your day!")

client.run('user token', bot=False)
```

Answer (score 0):

From the comments I'm assuming you want to use python.
This can be done using discord.py-self, it's mostly compatible with the discord.py library.

```py
import discord

class MyClient(discord.Client):
    async def on_ready(self):
        print('Logged on as', self.user)

    async def on_message(self, message):

        if message.content.find('hi'):
            await message.channel.send('hello')

client = MyClient()
client.run('put selfbot token here')
```